# Storing and querying interval tree in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data sets (lets assume it's integers for the example) which I want to store and query in Postgres.
For example:
Data set A: 1,7,9-13
Data set B: 1, 7, 10
I want to run query such as:
1. Is B a subset of A? (Yes)
2. What is the intersection of A and B?  (B)
The data sets can include thousands of integer ranges.
I was wondering if there is some extension which supports such data analysis.
Any examples / links will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the new range datatype: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html

Comment: I think the OP is more interested in sets, not necessarily ranges. If the sets are INTEGER sets, you might want to give  the `intarray` module a try. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/intarray.html

Comment: I believe I need an integer range array which is the combination of both comments ;-) Can the PostGIS help somehow ?

Comment: @AvnerLevy I am not familiar with PostGIS, but I don't think it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the range data types and store each disjoint type in a row.

For your sample:

```
-- The table
CREATE TABLE sets(id text, range int4range);
-- Values of set A
INSERT INTO sets VALUES('A', '[1,1]'),('A','[7,7]'),('A','[9,13]');
-- Values of set B
INSERT INTO sets VALUES('B','[1,1]'),('B','[7,7]'),('B','[10,10]');
```

To check if B is a subset of A, you can join both with all tuples that A's range contains B's range:

```
 SELECT b.range
 FROM sets b JOIN sets a
     ON a.range @> b.range
 WHERE a.id='A' AND b.id='B'
```

With that, you can check if all the values from set B are in the above result (which will mean that all the ranges of B is contained by at least one range of A):

```
 SELECT NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT 1 FROM sets q WHERE q.id='B' AND q.range NOT IN (
         SELECT b.range
         FROM sets b JOIN sets a
             ON a.range @> b.range
         WHERE a.id='A' AND b.id='B'
     ));
```

To get the intersection, you can cross join both and exclude the empty ones:

```
 SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT a.range * b.range AS intersec
     FROM sets a CROSS JOIN sets b WHERE  a.id='A' AND b.id='B'
 ) i WHERE NOT isempty(i.intersec);
```

One problem about this approach, is that you must keep only disjoint rangeS through different tuples. For instance, range [1,5] and [4,7] from a set must reside in a tuple with [1,7] only. To make sure of it, you can insert them into a temporary table (while inserting or updating), them cross join the table itself with tuples that overlaps and them join those and keep the others the way they are.

Answer (score -1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d85f2/1)

No need for arrays or ranges. It is just pure relational.

The interception is pretty obvious:

```
select v
from t
where set = 'A'
intersect
select v
from t
where set = 'B'
order by v
```

And the subset not much harder:

```
select count(*) = 0
from (
    select v
    from t
    where set = 'B'
    except
    select b.v
    from
        (select v from t where set = 'A') a
        inner join
        (select v from t where set = 'B') b on b.v = a.v
) s
```

Comment: Thanks for the example but the problem with this approach is that if I have a range such as [5, 50000000], I'll need to insert lots of records which makes it not practical in my case.

Comment: @Avner Where is the data coming from? It is easier to _fix_ it (make it relational) while entering the db than to be forever tied to complex queries and the risk of lost integrity.

Comment: My actual type is IP addresses and it isn't practical to insert every single one as a single row. but thanks for the help anyway.