# Storing IPv6 ranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ipv6, postgresql-9.2

In 9.2, new range functionality was added. 
How do I create a table with IPv6 ranges fields?
Do I need to create new type?
An example / link will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL already supports [type CIDR](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-CIDR), which can store ranges for both IPv4 and IPv6. The only catch that these ranges cannot be like `1.2.3.1-1.2.3.10` for IPv4 or `::5:1-::5-10`, but only like `1.2.3/28` or `2001:0:0:5::0/64` - typical for classless subnet declaration.

If you want more flexibility than `CIDR`, and want to have true arbitrary `INET` ranges, there is [`ip4r` extension](https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r-historical) what offers these ready to use. It is included by default in [some Ubuntu versions](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ip4r) (for example it is included in Ubuntu 12.10).

Don't be fooled by `ip4r` name: it supports both `IPv4` and `IPv6` since version 2.0. It also supports typical range operations that you would expect, like `BETWEEN`, `<<=` to check if IP belongs to range and some others. Read more here: [`README.ip4r`](https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r/blob/master/README.ip4r).

Comment: Thanks, but I need specific ranges of IPv6. In additional I want to define sets of ranges and compare them. That's why I need the range functionality. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187283/storing-and-querying-interval-tree-in-postgresql/15191972#15191972

Comment: I have updated answer to explain that it supports IPv6 and some operations that you need.